# How to send parameter to Method in Runtime Compilation

Tags: c#, runtime-compilation

I made a C# project in visual studio 2010 according to post:

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/RuntimeCompilation_1.aspx

I want read a txt file and Send Parameter to One Method then get Result.
Now my question is that how to send an argument or parameter to Method in Runtime Compilation?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/RuntimeCompilation_2.aspx has an example of invoking a method using reflection.  What you want to do is `Invoke` the method, e.g. `object result = myMethod.Invoke(null, myParam);` and look at `result`.

Comment: thanks for answer. yes i want do like object result = myMethod.Invoke(null, myParam); but i cant input myParam. now how set myParam in Invoke because had Compile error (e.g. "Hello World!").

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  What is it you're doing that's giving you a compilation error?  Are you giving the provider invalid code?